# Does C-3PO have color vision?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, c-3po

A quote from (though almost certainly not Legends-canon) [Star Wars Adventures in Colors and Shapes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Adventures_in_Colors_and_Shapes) suggests that he cannot:

> **C-3PO**: "Excuse me, Central Computer, but could you tell me if this
>   plate is red?"
>
> **Central Computer**: "No, that plate is green. Green is
>   the color of grass, and of leaves on the trees, and of Greedo."

However, in [Star Wars: Droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids_(video_game)) (also probably not Legends-canon), C-3PO solves a color puzzle.

In the Knights of the Old Republic RPG series, when you control a droid and view in first person they have monochrome vision, so perhaps that is the norm. However, I'd expect a protocol droid to need detailed vision.

I did not find much about C-3PO commenting on colors in a short search, and I don't remember anything from books. So, does C-3PO have color vision?

Comment: He knew he had a red arm in TFA.

Comment: In the quote, it sounds like he's asking if the color he's seeing is red.

Comment: @Jeeped: Do we know how he found out his arm was red? Did he simply see it, or did someone tell him?

Comment: @DeeV he's looking for a red plate to replace a damaged red plate. He (apparently) can't tell if the one he has is red or not. It's a children's book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [*Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2008155.Star_Wars_Blueprints) factbook, C-3PO has a [Mk.2 Myriad Visual System](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Myriad_Visual_System%E2%80%94MK._2) that gives him vision *equivalent to that of a human*. This presumably includes colour-vision.

> [image: C-3P0 information]
>
> <sub><sup>A salvaged MK. 2 Myriad Visual System allows C-3PO to see by human and various alien standards.</sup></sub>

The [*Star Wars: The Visual Encyclopedia*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Encyclopedia) factbook goes even further in describing his visual systems. In "human mode" he has the equivalent eyesight of a human, but in other modes he can see into the infra-red, lowlight night-vision and analyse gases.

> C-3P0's visual hardware and software allow him to see much more than the average human. Each of the settings of his Myriad Visual System—MK. 2 provides a unique optical advantage. **Human mode gives C-3P0 a standard visual reference**, while Infra-red mode lets him see at night. Other modes allow him to scan for properties such as gas composition, heat, or motion.

Comment: Shouldn't you provide a full transcript so readers can get more information, even if the image is not displaying?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - A full transcript isn't always necessary, but a partial one (of the relevant bits) is useful.

Comment: I thought one of the encyclopedia's would have it but I don't have one myself. This is a good answer.

Comment: @gormadoc - I find that it's useful to own practically every in-universe Star Wars factbook ever written